# not able to get data from route in flutter another screen by route setting

Tags: flutter, dart, oop, flutter-navigation

I want to pass the data of the song array in that title and description and id are there my code for the route is like this

```
onTap: ()  {
                          //toast message showing he selected song title
                          // print("${context} You Selected:   " + item.data![index].title);
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>  SongScreen(),
                            settings: RouteSettings(
                              arguments: item.data![index],
                            ),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
```

but at another class receiving side, I am not able to get the data I am getting an array of data  but not able to access one of theme like I am getting ['1', '0', '2'] but not able to access the single 1 at receiver side code is shown below

> final song = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments;

in between screen

```
Center(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Text('${song.title}'),
              ],
            ),
        ),
```

here for song.title getting error only song I am getting object but not able to get the title

printed details

```
{
title: 'abc',
id: 32
}
```

Comment: print song and check get data value

Comment: then i am getting all the things but all in details i want only one value

Comment: print out the details above for us to see.

Answer (score 0):

```
ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => abc(song: song),
                ),
              );
            },
            child: Text("Push me"),
          ),
```

```
class abc extends StatefulWidget {
  abc({Key? key, required this.song}) : super(key: key);
  Song song;
  @override
  State<abc> createState() => _abcState();
}

class _abcState extends State<abc> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text(widget.song.title),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
class Song {
  Song({required this.description, required this.title, required this.id});
  String description;
  String title;
  int id;
}
```

Comment: not getting at passing time in navigator getting error like string type cant assign to song type